# Project Reactor onErrorResume get stuck

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor, reactive-streams

I'm using project reactor and I have a very long flow in which I get an exception (when parsing a string to json with Jackson). The thing is that even though I use

```java
.map(this::parser)
.onErrorResume(err -> {
   log.error(myMsg);
   return Mono.empty();
})
.flatMap(writeToPulsar)
.subscribe()
```

The flow won't continue. I do see the error log and the flow doesn't throw an exception, but the flow won't continue to get executed. Any reason for this to happen?

When I change the code to the (unwanted) `.onErrorContinue()`, the data pipeline won't get stopped:

```java
.map(this::parser)
.onErrorContinue((err, msg) -> {
   log.error(myMsg);
})
.flatMap(writeToPulsar)
.subscribe()
```

Comment: like all Reactive Streams publishers, the `map` publisher stops when the exception happens in the mapping function, terminating the publisher with `onError`. The `onErrorResume` operator simply translates that `onError` terminal signal it receives into another concatenated publisher. The map is still terminated by the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a part of the error handling you are returning `Mono.empty()` and it means your flow will be completed without emitting any result and `flatMap` will not be executed.

Not sure about the expected behavior but if you want to continue the flow - return some "default" value from `onErrorResume` instead or use `switchIfEmpty` operator to provide another publisher.